# why my result is overriding in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def geteta(self,b=0,etatype="schedule"):
    eta_3_cuurtime = self.currtime + timedelta(hours = b)
    [self.a["legdata"].get(str(i)).append({'depdetails':self.func(self.a["legdata"].get(str(i))[2],eta_3_cuurtime,etatype,self.thceta)}) if i==1 else self.a["legdata"].get(str(i)).append({'depdetails':self.func(self.a["legdata"].get(str(i))[2],self.a['legdata'].get(str(i-1))[3]['depdetails'][2])}) for i in range(1,len(self.a['legdata'])+1)]
    eta1 = self.a["legdata"].get(str(len(self.a["legdata"])))[3]['depdetails'][2] #13. eta is last items depdetails [2] (available)
    return eta1 

def main(self):
    eta3 = self.geteta()
    eta4 = self.geteta(b=3)
```

when i am calling geteta method with different inputs my result (eta3,eta4) are same values.when i run method indiviual (comment first geteta) it is giving correct values.i know some where values are overriding but i am not able to figure out where it is.i hv struggling from couple of days for finding this but not.please help me in this

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use list comprehensions as a for loop and don't write your code all on one line. Help us help you.

Comment: Are you sure the lists from the two are exactly the same?  Your list comprehension is changing `self.a` by appending to it.  As a result, running this twice will just append to `self.a` meaning your `eta1[0]` for both `eta3` and `eta4` would be the same, leading you to believe they're the same list. 
 But they might be different on the end.  Are you checking the very end of these lists and seeing if there are different values at the end?

Comment: Also, using a list comprehension for simply mutating a list is kinda defeating the point.  You might as well just do a for loop at that point.  List comprehensions return a new list by default.  Using one to cram tons of separate functions makes it much less readable and intuitive.  Also, mutating the underlying list creates issues like you have now.  if you want to run the same function twice, you're now working with 2 different lists instead of the same list and returning a new working list and mutating that list.